# SSRS Report Adding Extra Pages When Converting to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2017

I have an SSRS report that has a master page with a tablix that has 1 cell, and in that cell is a subreport. To be safe I made this page 1in x 1in.

The subreport is linked to a report that is 8.5in x 11in. There is nothing on this report but a text box with a page number. The textbox cangrow property is false. The orientation for the report is set to portrait and paper size is letter.

Container consume whitespace is set to true for both, and neither page has margins, headers, footers, or padding.

The dataset for the tablix returns 1825 rows, but when the report is converted to PDF it is creating 2362 pages, and the page number is pushed progressively further down the page until blank pages appear.

Any idea how I make it 1825 8.5in x 11in pages?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was also defining the height/width in the query string when calling the report, which apparently caused problems. I changed:

http://test/ReportServer?/Folder/Reports/REP/REP_Master&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rc:PageHeight=8.5in&rc:PageWidth=11in&P_DB_NAME=TEST&P_BATCH_ID=9999999

To:

http://test/ReportServer?/Folder/Reports/REP/REP_Master&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&P_DB_NAME=TEST&P_BATCH_ID=999999

and it works.